# how can I use arabic light stemmer lib using java

Tags: java, text-classification

I have a search classification of Arabic text and I try use the Arabic light stemmer to do text processing but does not know how i do you can help me?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Comment: this is link of library: https://github.com/motazsaad/arabic-light-stemmer